# REST API / SOCKET or both on instant messaging application?

Tags: rest, api, websocket, instant-messaging

Is it necessary to build REST APIs for instant messaging application?

Or can everything be done with websocket?

For example I found:
 - Slack: uses REST API + Socket
 - RocketChat: uses only Socket (I did not see any XHR calls on chrome)

#### Let's say that the question is:

For a regular IM app with channels, group conversations and private chats which way is technically better?